# Need to render partial on completion of resque job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

I am using rails 2 and resque. I want to render a partial when resque job completes execution.
I know that we can use `render`, `redirect` etc methods in lib files.

Any suggestions for the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Admiting that what you want is to get the rendered output of a partial or a erb file from your resque job you can do something like this:

```
require 'erb'

weekday = Time.now.strftime('%A')
simple_template = "Today is <%= weekday %>."

# you can also read from a file like so ERB.new(File.read(<file name here>))
renderer = ERB.new(simple_template)
puts output = renderer.result()
```

You can read more here http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/

Comment: sorry, no luck... still not able to get what I need.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a solution to this for the last 3 days..

and finally found it here..

http://www.rigelgroupllc.com/blog/2011/09/22/render-rails3-views-outside-of-your-controllers/

This works for rails 4 as well!

```
av = ActionView::Base.new()
av.view_paths = ActionController::Base.view_paths
av.extend ApplicationHelper #or any other helpers your template may need
body = av.render(:template => "/orders/receipt.html.erb",:locals => {:order => order})
```

But the question is asking about a Rails 2 solution and the link above provides this code.

```
body = ActionView::Base.new(Rails::Configuration.new.view_path).render(:file => "/orders/receipt.html.erb",:layout => false,:locals=>{:order=>order})
```

Comment: Thanks @Hovo, however, I was looking for Rails 2 solution

Comment: Added the rails 2 solution that was also provided in the same link as the rails 4 solution